# What might cause MSBuild to behave differently from machine-to-machine?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a C# program (not ASP.NET or even web-related) with platform AnyCPU targeting .NET v3.5 that references a 32-bit third-party .dll. Unfortunately, I also have several "work of art" build machines in our CI pipeline that build this program. I'm trying to add another one but I can't figure out what allows it to build.

Whenever I try to build on this new machine, I get

> LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'ASSEMBLY' or one
>   of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.'

So far my only lead is that someone's installed several unneeded programs (visual studio 2010, several C++ runtimes, Windows SDK, etc) but those shouldn't break my build and I don't want to uninstall things willy nilly.

Here is the command which works on my old build machine and fails on my new one:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=release;Platform=AnyCPU;TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5 Utilities\UtilityGUI\UtilityGUI.csproj
```

If I change the `Platform` property to `x86` it works on both machines. Changing it to `x64` breaks it on both machines.

What could be causing this? I checked msbuild.exe.config on the machines and compared the registry under `SOFTWARE/Microsoft/VisualStudio` as well as `SOFTWARE/Microsoft/MSBuild`. I don't want to change code as it works on my other machines and branches that haven't had a merge yet couldn't build on this machine.

Comment: Cobbling your own build server to avoid a VS license is certainly a drastic mistake, penny-wise pound-foolish applies heavily.  This is a License Compiler error message, lc.exe has been troublesome in the past.  In some cases it is not present in an SDK folder where MSBuild expects it.  A Q&D workaround for that is copying lc.exe.  What will go wrong next is copying the wrong version, like the 32-bit instead of the 64-bit version.  This exception is the outcome.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I follow. Visual studio is licensed. Are you suggest the third party .dll isn't licensed for this new build machine? I agree that our build machines were put together in a 'penny-wise pound-foolish' manner and I was hoping I could use this knowledge to get away from that :)

Comment: I'm suggesting that *somebody* solved a previous build problem by copying lc.exe.  Which now breaks the build.  Find it back from a detailed build trace.

Comment: @HansPassant Please forgive me but, since yesterday, I've been trying to act on your advice and it's still broken. I've uninstalled/reinstalled windows sdks, visual studio, and .NET 4.5. I made sure to delete (read backup) LC.exe before doing all this and it was reinstalled successfully yet I still receive the error. I also re-registered my third-party control. If I've deviated from your advice somewhere or you have any more suggestions, please feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your 32-bit reference. You can't load a 32-bit assembly into a 64-bit process. Is there a reason why you can't target x86 exclusively?

As for why it's building on one machine and not the other, it may be that the AnyCPU profile on one machine is set to prefer 32-bit, or it may be that the machine that's successfully building is actually a 32-bit machine and is targeting x86 out of necessity. Either way, you won't be able to produce x64 builds when referencing a 32-bit dll.

Comment: Where do I check to see if AnyCPU is set to prefer 32-bit? To be honest, that sounds like a project-level setting because this enterprise software has lots of AnyCPU solutions in it that build as 64-bit. None of the working machines ones have a 32-bit OS. I'm not opposed to targeting 32-bit, I'm trying to avoid modifying source code that already works as well as increase personal understanding.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 go to a project's property page (right click -> properties), select the build tab. It should be right under platform target. You may just want to set it to x86 for that project, as the 3rd party library is going to restrict you to running in 32-bit.

Comment: That's source code though (or a .csproj file at least) which, since the .csproj is the same no matter the machine on which it's being built, I'd prefer not to change since I don't believe it's the problem. I'm trying to find whatever is wrong with the machine setup that's causing this.

Comment: Try building from command line on both machines with Platform=x64. I would expect it to fail on both.

Comment: You're right, they do both bomb. This is the command that works fine on one machine and throws a compile error on the other: `C:\WIndows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=release;Platform=AnyCPU;TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5 Utilities\UtilityGUI\UtilityGUI.csproj ` Changing Platform to `x64` breaks it on both machines and changing it to `x86` fixes it on both machines. However, I'd really like to avoid changing it in SVN in order to fix it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If you can also get a 64-bit binary you could make it possible to build on both machines, but you would still need to touch the related csproj to conditionally add the references based on the build target. Glad to help!